# undefined variable error in foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a problem where I use this `foreach` code. I receive an `undefined variable: task` error.

```html
<?
  $data = file_get_contents('data.json');
  $array = json_decode($data, 1);
  foreach ($array as $task) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <?= $task['name'] ?>
      </td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary"><?= icon('stop'); ?></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-danger"><?= icon('times'); ?></button></td>
    </tr>
  <? } 
?>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with JS/jQuery?

Comment: use the classical arsenal to see what happens, `ini_set('display_errors', 'On')`, `var_dump`, `print_r`, [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php).

Comment: I suspect you don't have `short_tags` enabled in your php.ini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add the start of php file `<?php` and at the end `<?php } ?>`, which will result in different errors

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('data.json');
$array = json_decode($data , 1);
foreach ($array as $task) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?= $task['name']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary"><?= icon('stop'); ?></button></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger"><?= icon('times'); ?></button></td>
    </tr>
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: Why should he try this? The answer should explain what was wrong in the original code and how you fixed it.